# Rails full text search appropriateness for "standard" queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, full-text-search, ransack, pg-search

Gems such as [Ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack) make it easy to search models, but obviously do not work so well for 
full text fields such as descriptions or comments, so I have been thinking of using [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) for all my searching (don't want to mix and match search solutions if possible) against any text field (names, descriptions, comments etc) and always doing full text searches as I can then search against any text field and get better results. Are there any problems with using full text search in such a manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK months later when I have actually used full text, I can safely say you use full text when searching through unstructured text, and SQL LIKE for everything else!